# Java - Plotting library

Tags: java, r

I am creating an application were I have to do a lot of mathematical calculations and finally print a report with the results(which consists of a lot of statistics/graphs etc.)

I thought about using R in my application. However I did not found a stable library?

Instead I want to use: `apache maths` and probably some plotting library(graphs).

Therefore,

Do you have any recommendations either on a RToJava and also on a java plotting library?

PS.: One thing I forgot: I am on time pressure on this project and therefore I need something that is stable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing some statistical analysis now, using apache-commons-math3 and JFreeChart. [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) itself is free but the developer manual is commercial. But there are plenty of examples and posts to be found on SO and the rest of the web, so if you don't want to buy the manual you can still find all you need to know but it requires a bit of searching.

JFreeChart is probably the most popular charting/plotting library for Java.